# 1000 mg/L alkalinity as CaCO3 standard preparation

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, reagents

How do I prepare a 1000 mg/L alkalinity as CaCO3 standard?  I found a method that says to dissolve 1.06 g of sodium carbonate (Na2CO3) in 1L of water but I'm not sure why I can't use 1g instead?  Thanks!

Comment: Do you suppose both substances have  the same molar mass ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the soloubility of calcium carbonate is very poor. It is 14 mg/l. So it is not possible to prepare a solution with 1 g/l, but instead you can use sodium carbonate, the soloubility 217 g/l. To get the same molarity you have to dissolve 1,06 g of it.